# How to use SSL for local development with Nitro?

Tags: config, ssl, nitro

I've created a new Craft CMS project and installed Nitro to run everything in a VM. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to use SSL for the local domain? I didn't found anything in the documentation.

Comment: SSL is not available on Nitro yet. It is on the roadmap, though. See https://github.com/craftcms/nitro/issues/10

Comment: @JoshuaM want to add that as an official answer, Joshua?

Comment: @BradBell Sure thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout Nitro 2, it now has full SSL support

https://craftcms.com/docs/nitro/2.x/commands.html#trust

Answer (score 1):

SSL isn't currently available in Nitro–though it is on the roadmap for development. See [github.com/craftcms/nitro/issues/10](https://github.com/craftcms/nitro/issues/10).